# Bring back "Copy, but keep both files" option in Windows 10? Some users seem to have it, others don't

Tags: copy-paste, copy

Somewhere during the release of Windows 8, the option to "keep both files" for whenever you copy a file with the same filename from a different directory was removed. It was instead replaced by a [moronic menu](https://www.windowsdigitals.com/wp-content/uploads/Copy-But-Keep-Both-Files-Windows-10.png) which forces you to needlessly wade through columns and checkboxes.

Some users have suggested using Teracopy instead (I looked through their ramshackle privacy policy, and ew). Some may have tried to hack their way into bringing it back (I haven't found any such examples). Most have merely resigned to their fate.

However, a very small number users have posted screenshots of using this exact option in Windows 10. Some on [this very website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65014451/powershell-select-option-copy-but-keep-both-files-by-default), while others have suggested that it was an option [brought back in build 11082](https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/3xizkf/why_is_there_still_no_keep_both_files_option_when/cy5k96t/).

What's really going on here? I'm on 22H2, is it only visible on certain Windows 10 versions?

P.S.: I'd really appreciate if someone could comment on the stackoverflow [guy's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10431776/paulo) [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65014451/powershell-select-option-copy-but-keep-both-files-by-default) to ask him how he did it, since I don't have enough rep to comment.

Comment: Consider Sync Back Pro:   https://www.2brightsparks.com/syncback/help/copydeletesettings.htm   .....  I use this and the Test facility to ensure my logic is correct.

Comment: I instead looked through alternativeto.com for some open-source alternatives to Teracopy, and Ultracopier seems to do the job (although so far I've noticed drag-to-extract in 7zip doesn't work with it - but I haven't encountered other issues yet).

Comment: And it seems copy/paste/cut operations which require admin privileges don't work with Ultracopier either.